# D3.brush scatterplot matrix, not changing appearance of map

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm implementing brushing where dragging a cursor over the bubbles of a scatter plot matrix will select the bubbles, and change the style class of the bubbles in another visualization.

This is my brush code:

```
function brush(p) {
    var e = brush.extent();
    var selected = {};

    scatter.selectAll(".dot").classed("selected", function(d) {

        var sel = e[0][0] > tx || tx > e[1][0]
      || e[0][1] > ty || ty > e[1][1];
        selected[d['id']] = sel;

        return sel;
    });

   map.selectAll(".dot").classed("selected", function(d) {
       return selected[d['id']];

   });
}
```

I've narrowed it down the event feed from d3.brush.extent. This is what I'm logging from the extent

I've narrowed it down to strange values for the extent. This is what I'm logging

E[0][0]: 1366664511350.9492 
E[1][0]: 1366664511395.322

E[0][0]: 3781.8181818181815
E[0][1]: 14618.18181818182

Clearly, my events are being recorded incorrectly somehow.

My current implementation is at

cs.usfca.edu/~jakutay/visualizations/salesview2.html

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663)? Especially the `brushmove` function.

Comment: Yes I have. But I'm not sure about this line: 
     return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1][0]
          || e[0][1] > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1][1];
When I try that, I see that p has no defined attribute 'x'. I think its trying to see if the datapoint is within the bounds of the rectangle made by the click event.

Comment: Yes, is that not what you're trying to do?

Comment: It is, but d[p.x] and d[p.y] aren't giving me the x and y values. I will try to get the x and y of the dots in a different way.

Comment: @Lars resolved that issue, dots still not changing on map